# I try working check_box_tag and mysql but why always insert data to Boolean is null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

below is my mysql table define

```
    class CreateStudinfors < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :studinfors do |t|
      t.string :cname , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.string :ename , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.date   :birthday
       t.string :gender , limit: 1, :null => false
       t.string :address , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.string :telephone , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.string :mobile_phone , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.string :school , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.string :email , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.boolean :work
       t.boolean :study
       t.boolean :travel
       t.boolean :lifeplan
       t.text     :other , :null => false
       t.string :sales , limit: 45, :null => false
       t.string :introduce , limit: 45, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

this is my part of my form ..

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :make select %><br />
    <%= check_box_tag "work" %>
  </div>
```

any advise? thanks and please

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show your form as well? If it is a form for a specific model such as:

```
<%= form_for @studinfor do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Then you need to create the check box like this:

```
<%= form_for @studinfor do |f| %>
   <%= f.checkbox :work %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just one correction, the real function to use is `f.check_box :work` with underscore ;)